# How do you use awaitMessages with mentions.users.first?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i'm trying to make a bot for my server and im attempting to create a command in which you ask the bot something, it replies, and you have to mention a user but i keep getting this error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
Here is my code:

```
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] }).then((collected => {
        console.log(collected.first().content);
        user = collected.mentions.users.first();
```

(this is my first post, so sorry if i did anything wrong)

Answer (score 0):

When using `async/await` the promise will be resolved into either the successful data or an error. Here you have used `await` keyword and applied `then` at the end of it. You shouldn't do it that way. This is an example of how you should make use of `async/await`:

```js
const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] });
console.log(collected.first().content);
user = collected.mentions.users.first(); // assuming user is already declared
```

Please take a look into the following references to learn more in depth:

- [About async/await from js info](https://javascript.info/async-await)
- [More about `await` keyword from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)